# Duvida orientação a objeto + ORM java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou querendo armazenar os dados do meu programa via ORM e estou separando bonitinho cada objeto.

Meu objeto Usuario por exemplo, tem seus atributos basicos e também é composto por outros objetos como Endereco,Contato e Acesso.

Cada objeto tem um atributo ID, para identificação e associação...

Minha duvida é a seguinte, no metodo construtor de cada classe(Usuario,Endereco,Contato e Acesso) Eu devo passar o id correspondente ou apenas os demais atributos? Porque eu acho, que de repente o hibernate possa atribuir o ID correto.

```
Public Class Cliente
   private long Id;
   private String Nome;

   Public Cliente(Long id,String Nome){} 
   'ou
   Public Cliente(String Nome){}  
   '?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Endereço`, `Contato` e `Acesso` são classes? Porque se sim, muito provavelmente temos um *pequeno* problema aqui. Sim, *pequeno*, sem ironias.

Essas informações são **agregadas** à um **usuário** – elas pertencem a ele e são compiladas conceitualmente como (meta) dados – em outras palavras, sem necessidade de projetá-las de classes para objetos; apenas as defina como variáveis de um **usuário**.

Sobre a herança, o **id** é **associativo**. Um usuário é uma coisa, um cliente é outra. Um usuário pode ser um cliente, bem como um representante ou administrador. O id(entificador) compartilhado entre as entidades (`usuario` e `cliente`) deve, contextualmente, ser o **mesmo** – um cliente é um usuário, mas não *necessariamente* o contrário.

Por fim, transformando isso em um idioma técnico:

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| #     | Usuário | Cliente |
+-------+---------+---------+
| Id    | 1       | 1       |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

Esse **id** vai pertencer sempre ao **usuário**, sem exceções. *Lembre-se: clientes são usuários; administradores são usuários; banidos são usuários. Independente da circunstância, organismos vivos são usuários.*

Para finalizar, você deve **definir** as características em comum de todos os usuários na dita cuja classe; nos filhos (administrador, cliente, representante, etc.) você adiciona suas particularidades MAS "pega emprestado" o **id** do pai.

Answer (score 0):

O Hibernate Trata ids relacionais como Objeto entao vc deve declarar com O Objeto Endereco ,Contato e Acesso dentro da classe Cliente se a sua tabela cliente tiver os campos idendereco, idcontato e idacesso e eles devem estar indexados com chaves estrangeiras.